# Laravel ORM relationship returns error when value not present in DB

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, fatal-error

I have an issue with querying relationships.
I am querying relations between Projects, Companies and Products. However, whenever a Project ID is not present in the database an fatal exception is trown:

> Call to a member function companies() on a non-object

```php
public function index($i) {
    return $this->returnTop($i, Array(
        'projectid' => 5,
        'products' => Array(1, 2, 3)
        )
    );
}

public function returnTop($count = 6, $args = Array()) {
    $companies = Project::find($args['projectid'])->companies()->whereHas('products', function($q) use($args) {
        $q->whereIn('products.id', $args['products']);
    })->with('products')->limit($count)->get();

    return Response::json($companies);
}
```

Now, I know that project id 5 is not present in the DB, and this is likely to be the cause of this error, but I want to return a message instead of the application throwing a fatal error....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to test whether the returned object is actually not null. Blindly assuming a database query succeeds is waiting for sh*t to hit the fan.

```
public function returnTop($count = 6, $args = Array()) {
    $project = Project::find($args['projectid']);
    if($project) {
        $companies = $project->companies()->whereHas('products', function($q) use($args) {
            $q->whereIn('products.id', $args['products']);
        })->with('products')->limit($count)->get();

        return Response::json($companies);
    }
    else {
        return; // .. your error or whatever
    }
}
```

Also the "call to a member function on a non-object" is quite specific, it tells you that a method (member function) could not be called due to the fact that you are trying to call it on a non-object.

Comment: In fact, I was blindly assuming the query would fail :) but I expected laravel to return different output. Your answer helped me out though. Thanks!

Comment: What use would an ORM have when throwing errors every time an entry does not exist. The proper result would be to say; "there is no entry" which is translated into `null`. But it's a common pitfall to blindly assume everything to work without proper validation; happens "here" all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Just check if `find()` returns `null`. Something like this:

```php
$project = Project::find($args['projectid']);
if(is_null($project)){
    return Response::json(['message' => 'Project not found']);
}
$companies = $project->companies()->whereHas('products', function($q) use($args) {
    $q->whereIn('products.id', $args['products']);
})->with('products')->limit($count)->get();

return Response::json($companies);
```

---

An alternative would be `findOrFail` which throws a `ModelNotFoundException`. You could handle the exception globally or catch it inside the controller:

```php
try {

    $companies = Project::findOrFail($args['projectid'])->companies()->whereHas('products', function($q) use($args) {
        $q->whereIn('products.id', $args['products']);
    })->with('products')->limit($count)->get();

    return Response::json($companies);

} catch (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e){
    return Response::json(['message' => 'Project not found']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for these solutions. I wish I could upvote it but I just registered an account and my reputation is too low..

Comment: No worries, I have enough of those internet points anyways ;)

Comment: Go with exception approach, much cleaner, I think documentation is missing where to put such code (if you want it to make global), do it in `/Exceptions/Handlers/Handler.php` inside method `render()`. @lukasgeiter Where do you put exceptions? Do you catch exceptions right where you need it? Is there any cleaner way? (I've read posts on SO and laracasts about this. I would like your opinion about the matter.)

Comment: @Kyslik I agree. To be honest I haven't done anything big with Laravel 5 where I needed global exception handling. However if an application gets bigger I'd definitely handle the most thrown exceptions globally (inside the render method)

Comment: @Kyslik Good tip, I was actually going to look into handling these kind of exceptions globally. Thanks!